# yii timepicker - show the current time

Tags: php, yii, timepicker

i am using yii timepicker extension for show the time.when i click the create new calllog i need to display automatically current time in the text field.i try get current time that field but difficult to do that.please anyone can help me solve the problem?

when i click the create calllog i can display like this

[image]

i need to see like this with current date and time

[image]

my view code,

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'calllog-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'date'); ?>

        <?php $this->widget('application.extensions.timepicker.timepicker', array(
             'model'=>$model,
             'name'=>'date',
             'options'=>
                array(
                    'dateFormat'=>'dd-mm-yy'
                )           
           )); 


       ?>       
       <?php echo $form->error($model,'date'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'restaurant_id'); ?>
        <?php //echo $form->textField($model,'restaurant_id'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'restaurant_id', $model->getRestaurant(),array('prompt' => '--Select Restaurant--')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'restaurant_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'contact_person'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'contact_person',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'contact_person'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'phone'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'phone',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'phone'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'feedback'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'feedback',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'feedback'); ?>
    </div>
```

anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a `value` parameter in `option` array. Something like this.

```
<?php $this->widget('application.extensions.timepicker.timepicker', array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'name'=>'date',
    'options'=>
        array(
            'dateFormat'=>'dd-mm-yy',
            'value'=>date('d-m-Y H:i:s'),
        ),
     )
 );
```